# Get list of mails from Gmail in Android

Tags: android, gmail

Have such kind of problem: I need to get list of mails form my gmail account. It`s shown in snippet below:

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.google");
File file = new File("content://gmail-ls/messages/"+accounts[0].name+"/");
if(file.exists())
{
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls/messages"+accounts[0].name+"/");
    cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
}
```

But it doesn't enter in "if" condition as such path does not exist. With out "if" condition it throws with exception on moment when I assign a cursor by a query with Uri to gmail-ls.
Anyone knows how this problem can be solved? Will appreciate any advice!

Comment: By the way, i have all essential permissions: 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.READ_GMAIL"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL"/>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not possible any more for third-party apps to read email from Gmail
ref http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/XD0C4sw9K7U/LpNXxFNnfgc